# How user can find out who open a file from shared folder ? (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, shared-folders, windows-server-2016

is there any possibility for a standard user to check who has opened a file on a network resource? I know you can check it on the server (Computer Management snap-in - System Tools → Shared Folders → Open Files). Sometimes the system shows in the window the name of the user who opened the word / excel file, but often not. Is there any setting in the system or can it be configured somehow?

Comment: *Sometimes the system shows in the window the name of the user who opened the word / excel file, but often not.* Username is not shown when it is unknown to server. It can be when the file is shared to everyone and/or anonymous access allowed. Disable anonymous and generic access, allow only locally registered accounts usage.

Comment: Isn't it visible in the file's property dialogue window directly via `explorer.exe`?  Can't confirm at the moment, but I remember being able to see which domain user last opened, modified, etc., at my workplace.